# Program to capture desktop screenshot in pure C

Tags: c, screenshot

I want to write a simple program to capture complete desktop screenshot in pure C on linux i.e no QT or Xlib

Comment: How can I build a great pyramid in my back yard without 100,000 slaves and a quarry?

Comment: @bmargulies: Simple: Import the stone along the Nile and use freemen, giving them work and putting food on their table outside the farming season!

Comment: @Ajish, This is not possible with the current C standard without going into OS internals or directly manipulating memory... Actually, it might be impossible using today's operating systems.

Comment: get your cellphone, take a picture and upload to facebook, then use fb's C api to download the most recent uploaded picture. yes?

Answer (score 3):

Simple: reimplement Xlib inside your program, or at least the portion of it you need to grab the screen. You should start by reading about the [X protocol](http://www.alleystoughton.us/eXene/X-protocol.pdf).

**Edit:** Maybe you should read the [Wikipedia page on the X protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol) before the formal specification. What you want is to send a `GetImage` X request, as documented on page 61 of the PDF linked above.

Comment: PS: do not take my answer too seriously, unless you have loads of spare time.

Comment: And a copious supply of slave labor.